# How to differ between "Subscribe for notification" and "Favorite" question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, favorites-notifications

My problem is Favorite button in questions. I want to use it as Favorite to book good questions or questions with good answers that I can later reference. But at the moment I more often using Favorite button simply to be notified about progress of solving question which I answered. It would be nice to separate booking and notification subscribtion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it for either of these things, but not both.

Notice on your user page under the preferences tab there is a checkbox:

> [ ] I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited

If you have this checked, you have bookmarks. If you leave it *unchecked*, the default, you have tracking of arbitrary questions.

I recommend **using your browser's bookmarking facility for plain vanilla bookmarking** -- Google Chrome has an excellent shared state bookmarking tool (through GMail accounts) built in, for example.

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139

Comment: Yes that is what I have to do. I just propesed some opinion that favorite is more like subscribe ...

Comment: On [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) there is no
`[ ] I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited`. There is only `[ ] Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags`. I am not sure how to subscribe to a question though