# How to see entire history of a question (including answer histories)?

Tags: support, answers, revisions-list

I asked a question, someone answered, and we had a ~10 comment exchange before he removed his answer completely. Now I can't figure out how to get the history of his answer.

Is there a way?

[This is the question in question =P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767396/checkboxes-and-jquery-behaving-strangely-in-opera-and-ie)

Comment: What would be the point of deleting things if everyone can just go view them in the history anyways?

Comment: Because the history would be hard to find. Only advanced advanced users would be interested in getting to it. Honestly I just want to PM the guy but I can't remember his user name.

Comment: You can check the Google cache or other caching websites to see if any grabbed a version which included that answer.

Comment: @animuson good tip about caching sites... this all happened in a period of about 30 minutes so I'm not finding any cached results.

Comment: If you'd like to keep an archive of your responses, then [RSS feeds are useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90772/how-to-keep-track-of-questions-im-answering/90784#90784).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted questions and answers are available to anyone that has more then 10k reputation. Unless a moderator cleaned up the comments and deleted the answer, it will be available to you once you reach the required reputation, or someone with the required reputation posts it here as an answer.

Considering that most users do not want to be contacted, if you know the user you can search for him or her directly and contact them if they provided their contact details, or if they participate in chat. However, to me, if they deleted the answer, they most likely don't want to discuss it further, and have given up, either because they agreed with your comments, or because they felt it was becoming more effort then what the answer was worth. I know I have done the latter in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the info about 10k rep. You're probably right about the answerer giving up... although I did have a meaningful follow-up question for him. Oh well...