# How to keep track of changed questions/answers you already have voted on?

Tags: feature-request, voting

If the content of a question or answer I've already voted on is changed, I would like to revisit this change to see, whether my upvote or downvote is still valid after this change.

I know that we have a [Votes Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go) in our profiles and this allows us to filter casted upvotes and downvotes. But this list doesn't tell us, if a question/answer has been changed after voting. Manually clicking this list's entries one by one to find out is impractical, especially if you have hundreds or thousands of votes casted.

I know that one could misuse the Favorites feature and [mark questions as favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work). This at least [notifies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90772/how-to-keep-track-of-questions-im-answering) when any answer of the favorited posts gets changed. But it also wouldn't tell in which post *exactly* the change has happened, so this results in the same dilemma as mentioned above.

Can we have a feature that allows us to keep track of changed questions/answers we've already voted on?

I'm totally open on how to implement such feature, but to make at least one suggestion:

Maybe having some control (button, link, etc.) within the "upvote" and "download" sections of the Votes Tab, allowing us to switch the sort order from "Newest to oldest" to "Content changed in the last 30 days"?

**Edit #1:**

I've overlooked that the Favorites tab has an "activity" button.

But should I really add each post I've voted on to the favorites?

I usually use favorites to look-up or for reference purposes only.

Misusing the favorites to add each post I've voted on would render this useless, wouldn't it?

**Edit #2:**

After reading Ben's post [Indicate revisions in vote history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/indicate-revisions-in-vote-history) and his related [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143262/how-to-keep-track-of-changed-questions-answers-you-already-have-voted-on#comment-407213), I'd say combining both of our suggestions would make a real good match.

Having an "activity" sort within the up-/downvote sections of the Votes Tab and additionally maybe having `% edit and revision count` infos in the vote lines would make it a very good and useful feature.

Comment: @YannisRizos but if I vote on 30-40 questions/answers a day, that's a lot of favorites to manage (and watch for changes). Plus favoriting a question doesn't really guide you on changes made to a specific *answer* you've up- or down-voted. I'm not sure if I agree with this specific request but I don't think favorites is a valid workaround.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have no idea what you're talking about, good sir! (Heh, I've deleted the comment few seconds after I posted it, I didn't think anyone other than perhaps the OP saw it - agreed, not a good idea).

Comment: @YannisRizos interesting, seems I had enough time to respond before you deleted.

Comment: Related: [Indicate revisions in Vote History](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139270/indicate-revisions-in-vote-history)

Comment: @BenBrocka: +1, I basically like your idea, but if the order of the up-/downvotes still remains "Newest to oldest", users would still need to manually scan through dozens or hundreds of pages.

Comment: @JürgenThelen I can see adding a "by most changed" or "activity" sort

Comment: @BenBrocka: yep, "activity" is very similiar and I'd say even better than the "Content changed in the last 30 days" thingy, I suggested.